# Matrix array send to mail PHP

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

how to split it end send via mail() funcion? The message in email should be without any indexes, words Array, just clear text from array displayed in lines.

Code

array loks like this
    $test=array(array($info, $info1, $info2),array($info, $info1, $info2)array($info, $info1, $info2))

and php mail funcion

```
mail();
```

I know php but i don figure out how split the array and set in in one variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the array, store the values in a string, then send the string in email.  For example:

```
$str = '';
foreach ( $yourArray as $v ) {
    if ( is_array($v) {
        foreach ( $v as $v2 ) {
            $str .= $v2;    
        }
    } else {
        $str .= $v; 
    }
}
// $str goes to email
```

Note that this code is just an example.  It won't necessarily work with your array.  You'll need to modify it to work with your array structure. Arrays are essential to PHP, so I suggest reading the PHP manual, especially https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: I remove second foreach bescause I always have 3 elements, and I add some words to explain the values, thnx. just have one question what .= means?

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace() function
for more detail look this link
https://www.php.net/str_replace